# If both $f(x)>0$ and $g(x)\gt 0$ is $\arg\max(\log(f(x)g(x))) = \arg\max(f(x)g(x))$?

Tags: calculus, functions, optimization

Is it true that if both $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are positive for every $x$, is $\arg\max(\log(f(x)g(x))) = \arg\max(f(x)g(x))$?

Comment: Please show what you have tried. Also, where did you get this problem from?

Comment: Assuming * means *multiply*, consider how $\log(f(x) \times g(x))$ can be rewritten

Comment: This is not an assignment. It's a practical question for simplifying an optimization problem I have according to my intuition. i.e. I don't mind receiving any proof, I take your word :D. But from the comment, I assume it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write $fg = h$, where $h > 0$. Then you are asking if $\arg\max \log h = \arg\max h$. Let $x^* = \arg\max h$ and consider $\log hx^*$. Since $h(x^*)$ is the largest value of $h$, this is the largest input to $\log$. So, the domain of $\log$ is $[0, h(x^*)]$. Since $\log$ is increasing, it is maximized at $h(x^*)$. Hence, $x^* = \arg\max \log h$.